# Uncaught ReferenceError: randomnumber is not defined at test.js

Tags: javascript, object, referenceerror

i really dont know what im missing, when i want to create a new object from my class:
i have a class that generates randomnumbers and random names from another Helper class:

this is my class randomnumber:

```
class randomnumber {

    constructor() {
        this.age= getRandomNumber(0, 100);
        this.name = getNextName();
    }

    toString() {
        return (this.name + " (" + this.age+ ")");
    }

    equals(other) {
        if (this.age!= other.age)
            return false;
        if (this.name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (this.name != other.name)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

this is my Helper class:

```
var seed = 1;
function random() {
    var x = Math.sin(seed++) * 10000;
    return x - Math.floor(x);
}

const names = [ "Michael", "Laura", "Elias", "Julia", "Kevin", "Emma", "Luca",
        "Anna", "Alexander", "Lena", "Liam", "Lisa", "Marcel", "Vanessa",
        "Lea", "Leo", "Michael", "Daniel", "Mila" ];

function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getNextName() {
    let index = getRandomNumber(0, 100);
    index = index % (names.length-1);
    return names[index];
}
```

those two classes should work perfectly fine, but still if i want to call a new object from the class randomnumber like this:

```
let x = new randomnumber();
```

it always gives me a uncaught reference error on the new randomnumber() !?
in my html file all the skripts are included..

i just dont get it why the reference error is occurring, since i did the same thing in a lot of other cases where it used to work

Comment: doesn't look related to the code listed here.  Not seeing any usages of $.  Are you confident this is happening when you new up a randomnumber instance?

Comment: It says "Uncaught ReferenceError: randomnumber is not defined
    at test.js"

Comment: Yeah, that's a little bit different.  Are you transpiling?  How are you loading this class?

Comment: Its working for me check [here](https://codepen.io/nipunjain17/pen/BaNBjVE)